# CSV is overwriting in Python, instead of adding rows to CSV file

Tags: xml, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I am transforming an XML document into a CSV using a series of lists, so that I can leave out particular parts of the XML data. My code appears as the following:

```
tree=ET.parse('Comments.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
dict={}
Score=[]
PostID=[]
ID=[]
CreationDate=[]
UserID=[]
for child in root:
    dict.update(child.attrib)
    Score.append(dict['Score'])
    PostID.append(dict['PostId'])
    ID.append(dict['Id'])
    CreationDate.append(dict['CreationDate'])
    UserID.append(dict['UserId'])
with open('Comments.csv','wb') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
    for x in (0,174304):
        writer.writerow([Score[x],PostID[x],ID[x],CreationDate[x],UserID[x]])
```

I realize there may be cleaner ways of doing the above, but have not really been able to find them and am not entirely comfortable working with XML regardless. Unfortunately, the document that I am creating (Comments.csv), contains only a pair of row observations, as opposed to 174305. Similar problems have been shown on this site to be because the

```
with open('Comments.csv','wb')
```

portion is in a loop, meaning the document is opening repeatedly and writing over itself again and again. Mine is not in a loop, though, and my output ends up being

```
5      3       1    2010-07-19T19:15:52.517   13
1   115374  221292  2014-09-14T02:04:27.553   805
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening and how I might go about fixing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would using the append code work instead of the 'wb'?

```
with open('Comments.csv','a') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
```

Comment: unfortunately not, this just adds the same two entries.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem with this code was actually the way that I was doing the for loop. In the code above, you can see that I did not have the 'xrange' or 'range' statement, so the program was actually simply doing the first and last entries in the range as opposed to any of the others. Thanks for your help!